# How to store special signs like $ dollar and € euro in database via form

Tags: php, mysql, json

When i type in a amount with a special sign like: €140 via my form it stores it in my db exactly the same, But when i try to retrieve the amount it gives a strange signs instead of showing the special character normal. How do i need to store the special kind of signs to be able to retrieve it succesfuly?

Comment: Learn about encoding, so you understand how you store and retrieve data. Be it from a browser or from the database.

Comment: `$` works fine, however the euro character does not. You could store them as HTML entities (`&euro;`), but choosing the correct database encoding is much better. Try UTF-8.

Comment: also look at htmlentities() and html_entity_decode(). You might need to pass UTF-8 as the $charset parameter to them as well.

Comment: The absolute minimum you need to konw about unicode: 

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're using UTF-8 throughout your system (HTML doc type, PHP settings, MySQL settings).

Also, make sure you're calling htmlentities($string_to_print) when trying to display a given string.